# Converting ASP.NET page to MVC Controler HttpContext.Current error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to convert ASP.NET page to MVC Controler and get a build error.

*'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found*

This is the line of code that I need to convert from ASP.NET to MVC

```
 byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
```

The compiler underlines the: HttpContext.**Current**.Request.ContentLength

Comment: I know that this is very old. But any resolution? None of the answers so far, solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HttpContext.Request.ContentLength

Answer (score 2):

try using `ControllerContext.HttpContext.Current`